# What is the condition for two extreme points?

Tags: calculus

I am new to the topic of extreme point and trying to get the whole picture. Now I know the extreme theorm that mentions two condition to obtain a critical points what are $f'(x)= 0$ or $f'(x)=$ undefined.

I solved some examples of those on Khan Academy but coming across this example $\mathrm{Let} \, a,b,c,d, \in \, \mathbb{R}, a\neq0, f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=a\,x^3 + b \,x^2 + c\, x + d.$

- (a) What is the condition for two extreme points?
- the answer supposed to be (a) $\,b^2>3ac$.

> Can I know how and which topic this fall into?

Comment: Compute the derivative $f'(x)$ and once you get a second degree equation $f'(x)=0$, ask yourself how can you guarantee that it has distinct  real roots. It's a basic calculus question about zeroes of a derivative.

Comment: This question does not seem related to the Extreme Value Theorem – the function is considered on $\mathbb R$, whilst the [EVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) requires it to be defined on a closed interval of real numbers. Shouldn't it be re-tagged somehow...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you calculate de $f'(x) = 0$, you will see the condition for the "square root" to be positive (you fall into a quadratic equation), is $$\sqrt{(b^2 - 3ac)},$$
so, to be positive, you'll need $$b^2 > 3ac.$$
After this you can exploit the signals of $a$ and $c$, if you want it.